# Parameters with square brackets are converted to parameters with indices in the url of admin panel wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

For example: send a request like wp-admin/index.php?a[]=4&a[]=5, after refreshing the page in the address bar we see a[0]=4&a[1]=5. Why is this happening? I want to get the parameter using URLSearchParams.getAll("a"), but since the keys become a[0] and a[1], it doesn't work.